# Python: saving mouse position in one list

Tags: python, listener, pynput

In the following python code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

coord = []

def click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        coord.append(x)
        coord.append(y)

        if len(coord) == 4:
            print(coord)
            return
        
with Listener(on_click = click) as Listener:
    Listener.join()
```

what I want to do is ;
the code will stop when `coord` has 4 elements.
so like, this `If` will stop when I do click twice.

Comment: You are appending 2 items each click, you want to append `(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you append the x and y value individually every time. Each mouse click is stored as 2 values(the x and y). That is why instead of the code stopping at 4 clicks it stops at 2 clicks. To fix this, append a tuple or list(I've used a tuple)

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

coord = []

def click(x,y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        coord.append((x,y)) # You can use a list also here.

        if len(coord) == 4:
            print(coord)
            return
        
with Listener(on_click = click) as Listener:
Listener.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It works. However, can you please let me know how to retrieve only one element of tuple? 

Like, if I enter coord[0], it only retrieve (x1,y1) right? But I need to retrieve x1 only.

Comment: Use `coord[0][0]`. As when you use coord[0] it returns (x1,y1) then you can get the item in the first index of the tuple by simply adding another `[0]`.